How can high severity alerts be configured in Amazon RDS SQL Server?
Per the RDS documentation,

SQL Server Agent alerts and operators aren't supported.

But on any sensible SQL Server, you really want these for the high severity alerts.
So, I'm here to ask: How can high severity alerts be configured in Amazon RDS SQL Server? Is there an RDS alternative so powerful that you don't need them any more?

This is a question best asked to Amazon support. Otherwise, you'd have to use a 3rd party monitoring tool.

@J.D. This is such a basic SQL Server feature that I fully expect somebody else to have already solved the problem.

The feature perhaps, but Amazon's limitation of said feature is very specific and only a small group of people in the same exact boat as you who also care about the problem probably exist. As is evident from the lack of replies here and the upvotes on my original comment.

You might want to look into aws_db_event_subscription if you use terraform or manually configure them. Not sure if the level of granularity will match, but a big chunk of things worthwhile can be subscribed to.

I suspect that this list is worth linking, but I do not know if is is complete. The lack of results for "corruption" was scary.

RDS is a different beast. SSMS UI has many things disabled that one is typically accustomed to. It is a patchwork of a system built to minimize manual operations and just drop naturally into the generic apis that encompass RDS with its support of multiple RDBMS backends. In order to provide a one size fits all for 8 or 9 RDMS systems, some functions of the "supported" systems become non-supportable features. If you need the type of functionality you get with standalone SQL Server, then you may look into placing instances on EC2s instead, also the licensing cost are generally cheaper that way.

I did find an article on how to use send_dbmail in RDS, perhaps you can pull monitoring stats yourself and use your own notifications. https://repost.aws/questions/QUlhAoIbkFRQSwPFCS9qW3aQ/add-support-for-agent-operators-and-email-notifications-in-rds-for-sql-server

I may be missing your point. What does any of this have to do with SSMS?

@J.Mini - Not much unless you use it to access an RDS Sql Server instance.
